# Measure Glyphs Texts Width

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried measure text height in vertical lines.
and I want to get texts height without padding.

can I take it?

I tried.

Xaml

```
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  >

   <StackPanel Background="PowderBlue">

      <Glyphs
         x:Name              = "MyText"
         FontUri             = "C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\TIMES.TTF"
         FontRenderingEmSize = "100"
         StyleSimulations    = "BoldSimulation"
         UnicodeString       = "Hello World!"
         Fill                = "Black"
         OriginX             = "100"
         OriginY             = "200"
      />

   </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Code Behind

```
public double GetWidth(){
    return MyText.RenderSize.Width;
}
```

but my method returns null object.

Comment: "my method returns null object" - in case you mean MyText, InitializeComponent was not yet called.

Comment: I set loaded event, then I could get width. But I got panel width. I want text width. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, set the Glyphs HorizontalAlignment to something else than Stretch, e.g. Left. Is there a specific reason for using the (somewhat exotic) Glyphs class?